# Does Bluetooth 4.0 improve audio quality?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

> *I [moved a part of this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192489/does-bluetooth-4-0-improve-audio-quality) from the Electrical Engineering forum here,
>   since I was suggested that it is more appropriate here.*

I ordered a pair of [Bluetooth headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FZLV9L8) which apparently work on Bluetooth 4.0 but my computer only supports Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR.

[...]

Would upgrading my computer's Bluetooth improve the audio quality if I use the headphones over a Bluetooth 4.0 adapter or do I get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Would upgrading my computer's Bluetooth improve the audio quality?

Bluetooth 4.0 should improve audio quality, provided you have devices that support [aptX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX) or [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29):

- [aptX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX), an audio codec
  designed for [CD-quality audio transfer over Bluetooth](http://www.csr.com/products/60/aptx).
- [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29), or Advanced Audio Distribution Profile, which is designed for sending
  stereo audio over Bluetooth to speakers, car stereos, and headphones.

---

#### Does Bluetooth Audio Still Suck?

> The problem with Bluetooth audio has always been digital compression:
>   in order to send your audio to your headphones, you were forced to
>   sacrifice quality. Traditionally, especially on older devices and with
>   older Bluetooth versions, this meant the sound was so badly compressed
>   that the result sounded robotic, buzzy, noisy, and all around awful.
>
> Listening to podcasts and spoken word through them wasn't a big deal,
>   but when it came to music, they were just the worst. You got none of
>   the richness or warmth of sound that a pair of wired headphones
>   offers.
>
> In addition to compression just ruining the audio quality, there are
>   other factors at play. For one, Bluetooth rides the same 2.4Ghz
>   wireless frequency that so many other things in your home, like
>   wireless mice or keyboards, Wi-Fi signals, or even microwaves.
>
> Those things won't have a huge impact on sound quality, but they
>   can—and often do—cause audio drops and other quirks. Of course, all of
>   those are reasons why Bluetooth audio was never—and still isn't—a
>   match for traditional wired audio. That doesn't mean it's without its
>   merits.
>
> ...
>
> Bluetooth has improved, and the audio compression isn't nearly as bad
>   as it was even five years ago. Bluetooth standards have improved
>   significantly since the days of Bluetooth 1.1 and 2.0 (which is when
>   Bluetooth headsets and headphones really hit the market), and today's
>   Bluetooth 3.0 and 4.0 devices are built with more attention to stereo
>   audio in mind.
>
> If you want the best possible audio quality from a Bluetooth device,
>   look for headphones and speakers that support [aptX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX), an audio codec
>   designed for [CD-quality audio transfer over Bluetooth](http://www.csr.com/products/60/aptx). Alternatively,
>   look for support for [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29), or Advanced Audio Distribution Profile,
>   which also requires [compatible devices](http://www.mobileburn.com/definition.jsp?term=A2DP), but is designed for sending
>   stereo audio over Bluetooth to speakers, car stereos, and headphones.
>   In either case, even if you don't have supported devices, you may be
>   able to find adapters to help bridge the gap.
>
> That said, it's still not as good as wired audio, and some people say
>   it's still unacceptable overall. Still, there are situations where
>   it's good enough for what you want.

Source [Does Bluetooth Audio Still Suck?](http://lifehacker.com/does-bluetooth-audio-still-suck-1505063323)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! I checked on the manufacturer's website for details on aptX and A2DP. It seems that these headphones only support A2DP.